# Is there a way to get bounding box co-ordinates of detected objects from yolov3 darknet?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I am working with yolov3 object detection,

I wanted to get the co-ordinates of detected objects, if there is a method to get the co-ordinates?

Comment: Add `-ext_output` flag when using `darknet detect`.

Comment: Can I know which section of code prints that once we activate the -ext_output flag, I wanted to do some changes to that.

Comment: You need to dig into source codes in C.